# Synchronous web service calls in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, adobe, synchronous

Does adobe flex supports synchronous web service calls? Please justify your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300372/programming-synchronous-web-service-calls-in-flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Synchronous_data_calling_with_Flex-7184.html

[also here is some useful discussion](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/60616) and I'd lie to advice you to use GOF architecture of your project.

Would you mind to explain whats for you need this synchronous calls?